# Dropdown not getting correct value

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using the following to populate a combobox but I am setting the current entity value to what is in the drop down and the is changed via what row is selected on the treeview.

```
            dpParentId.DisplayMember = "Value";
            dpParentId.ValueMember = "Key";
            dpParentId.DataSource = cmsContext.GetAllCategoriesFromLookupDropDown();

              public Dictionary<int, string> GetAllCategoriesFromLookupDropDown()
      {
         Dictionary<int,string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();

           try
        { //for a common table to work i neaded some way to have it that their a blank entry so zero cant be so i have choosen 3 
            foreach (CustomLookup cs in cmsEntities.CustomLookups.Where(a=> a.LookupType==1))
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(cs.ID), cs.Description);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetAllCategoriesFromLookupDropDown failed.", ex);

        }

        return list;
    }
```

Then on my treeview selectedchanged event i have the following

```
     private void rgStandardLookup_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                currentEntity = null;
                try
                {  
                bool oldDataChanged = dataChanged;

            if (rgStandardLookup.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {

                currentEntity = rgStandardLookup.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as CustomLookup;
                  txtCode.Text = currentEntity.Code.ToString();
                  txtDescription.Text = currentEntity.Description;
                  chkParent.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(currentEntity.isParent) ? true : false;
                    LookupType = Convert.ToInt16(currentEntity.LookupType);
                  dpParentId.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt16(currentEntity.ParentLookUpID);
                }

                }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionBox.Show("An error occurred in the rgStandardLookup_SelectionChanged", ex);
                }

            }

    private void dpParentId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (currentEntity != null)

                { //   currentEntity.ParentLookUpID = Convert.ToInt16(dpParentId.SelectedValue);


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionBox.Show("An error occurred in the dpParentId_SelectedIndexChanged", ex);
            }
        }
```

Problem is is staying as the first item its not changing based on the value in the database

ID  Code    Name    Description ParentLookUpID  LookupType  isParent
15  0   NULL        15  1   NULL
2   1   .NET    .NET    NULL    1   1
3   2   Foxpro  Foxpro  2   1   0
4   3   HTML    HTML    NULL    1   1
5   4   SQL SQL NULL    1   1
6   5   PAMS    Pams    NULL    1   1
7   6   C#  C#  NULL    1   1
8   7   VB.NET  VB.NET  NULL    1   1
14  8   NULL    test    NULL    NULL    NULL

so in the drop down it should show 2 for foxpro but its not its staying number 15 ? my main problem is when i try to set the selected value its not being reconized on the drop down its just sitting to record 15 the blank one which is for an empty row

Comment: Please narrow down the long story to the problem.

Comment: @FeliceM added comment its when i trying to set the drop down value its just showing blank not changing to two for fox pro

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a delegate to sync the two dropboxes